Open $G$-orbit in spherical varieties
Let $X$ be a $G$-variety, that is an irreducible variety with a regular action of a connected reductive linear algebraic group $G$.
We say that $X$ is spherical if $X$ contains an open $B$-orbit, where $B$ is a Borel subgroup of $G$.
A (supposedly immediate) corollary is that a spherical variety contains also an open $G$-orbit. The only line of proof I've seen in books is that, given $x$ a point in the open $B$-orbit of $X$, then the orbit $G\cdot x$ is open in $X$.
I don't understand why this result holds. By definition
$$G\cdot x =\{g\cdot x\mid g\in G\}\supset \{b\cdot x\mid b\in B\} = B\cdot x$$
By taking closure, I see tha $\overline{G\cdot x} = X$, and I know that $G\cdot x$ is a locally closed subset of $X$, but these do not seem to help
.

$Gx =GBx=\bigcup_{g \in G}gBx$ is a union of open subsets, because $gBx$ is open for any $g \in G$.
